# How to exactly position an Image inside an existing PDF page using PDFBox?

Tags: pdfbox

I am able to insert an Image inside an existing pdf document, but the problem is,

1. The image is placed at the bottom of the page
2. The page becomes white with the newly added text showing on it.

I am using following code.

```
List<PDPage> pages = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

if(pages.size() > 0){
    PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(pdDoc, in);
    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDoc,pages.get(0));
    stream.drawImage(img, 60, 60);
    stream.close();
}
```

I want the image on the first page.

Answer (score 13):

PDFBox is a low-level library to work with PDF files. You are responsible for more high-level features. So in this example, you are placing your image at `(60, 60)` starting from lower-left corner of your document. That is what `stream.drawImage(img, 60, 60);` does.

If you want to move your image somewhere else, you have to calculate and provide the wanted location (perhaps from dimensions obtained with `page.findCropBox()`, or manually input your location).

As for the text, PDF document elements are absolutely positioned. There are no low-level capabilities for re-flowing text, floating or something similar. If you write your text on top of your image, it *will be* written on top of your image.

Finally, for your page becoming white -- you are creating a new content stream and so overwriting the original one for your page. You should be *appending* to the already available stream.

The relevant line is:

```
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream( pdDoc, pages.get(0));
```

What you should do is call it like this:

```
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream( pdDoc, pages.get(0), true, true);
```

The first `true` is whether to *append content*, and the final `true` (not critical here) is whether to *compress* the stream.

Take a look at [AddImageToPDF](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java) sample available from [PDFBox sources](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html).

Comment: ``PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage, boolean appendContent, boolean compress)`` is deprecated on ``2.0.0``

Comment: since method PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage, boolean appendContent, boolean compress) is deprecated new way to append content is:   PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, APPEND, true);

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
doc = PDDocument.load( inputFileName );
PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream( image )
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 425, 675 );
contentStream.close();
```

This prints the image in first page. If u want to print in all pages just put on a for loop with a condition of number of pages as the limit.
This worked for me well!

Answer (score 2):

So late answer but this is for who works on it in 2020 with Kotlin: drawImage() is getting float values inside itself so try this:

```
val file = File(getPdfFile(FILE_NAME))
val document = PDDocument.load(file)
val page = document.getPage(0)
val contentStream: PDPageContentStream
contentStream = PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true)

// Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
val bitmap: Bitmap? =        ImageSaver(this).setFileName("sign.png").setDirectoryName("signature").load()

val mediaBox: PDRectangle = page.mediaBox
val ximage: PDImageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap)
           
contentStream.drawImage(ximage, mediaBox.width - 4 * 65, 26f)

// Make sure that the content stream is closed:
contentStream.close()

// Save the final pdf document to a file
pdfSaveLocation = "$directoryPDF/$UPDATED_FILE_NAME"
val pathSave = pdfSaveLocation
document.save(pathSave)
document.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am creating a new PDF and running below code in a loop - to add one image per page and below co-ordinates and height and width values work well for me.

where *out* is BufferedImage reference variable

```
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    outputdocument.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(outputdocument, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
    PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(outputdocument, out);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 5, 2, 600, 750);
    contentStream.close();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Answer (score 0):

This [**link**](https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.html) gives you details about ***Class PrintImageLocations***.
This PrintImageLocations will give you the x and y coordinates of the images.

Usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.examples.util.PrintImageLocations input-pdf